# Fill the currrent data to bootstrap form

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using the bootstrap4 framework for my web application. Here's my requirement
I have a table generated with some values & each row has a edit button at the end of the row (last column).
when edit button is clicked, it should pop up a form with existing data in the row. So that user can change only the refuired fields. I know this should be done using javascript to fill the text boxes in the current form. But with  bootstrap4 framework i dont know the correct way to do this .
This is my table

```
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-hover table-dark">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Channel No</th>
          <th scope="col">Channel Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Descrption</th>
          <th scope="col">Recording Status</th>
          <th scope="col">Edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>TV 1</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
           <td>Y</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLoginForm">
  Edit
</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>TV 2</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
           <td>Y</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td colspan="2">TV 3</td>
           <td>Y</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">4</th>
          <td colspan="2">Derana</td>
           <td>Y</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">5</th>
          <td colspan="2">TV 5</td>
           <td>Y</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">6</th>
          <td colspan="2">TV 6</td>
           <td>Y</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">7</th>
          <td colspan="2">TV 7</td>
           <td>Y</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the edit button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLoginForm" >
  Edit
</button>
```

This is my POP form(modal) for the edit button

```
<div id="ModalLoginForm" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
           
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" method="POST" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Channel No</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="channelid" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Channel Name</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="channel">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="description">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        
                      <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Channel Recordable
                                </label>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
 
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
              
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fully working `code` and more **dynamic** approach to what you want. You can use native `boostrap` jQuery function to `show` your modal on `edit` click button in your row.

You can `watch` which button `triggered` the modal and from their you can grab all the data using jQuery function like [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Once you have the respective row data you can then apply it to your `form` input which are in the `modal`

In addition, i have also a functionality where recording status is `Y` then the checkbox in the modal will automatically be checked and if its `N` then it will be unchecked.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$("#ModalLoginForm").on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) //Button that triggered the modal

  //get data
  var cId = button.closest('tr').find('th').text() //1st th
  var cName = button.closest('tr').find('th').next().text() //2nd th
  var cDesc = button.closest('tr').find('th').next().next().text() //3 th
  var isRecord = button.closest('tr').find('th').next().next().next().text() //4 th

  //Apply data
  $('[name="channelid"]').val(cId);
  $('[name="channel"]').val(cName);
  $('[name="description"]').val(cDesc);
  //check the checkbox
  if (isRecord == 'Y') {
    $('[name="remember"]').prop('checked', true); //check the checbox
  } else {
    $('[name="remember"]').prop('checked', false);
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Channel No</th>
        <th scope="col">Channel Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Descrption</th>
        <th scope="col">Recording Status</th>
        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>TV 1</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLoginForm">
            Edit
          </button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>TV 2</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLoginForm">
            Edit
          </button></td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>TV 3</td>
        <td>dfdf</td>
        <td>N</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLoginForm">
            Edit
          </button></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th scope="row">4</th>
        <td>TV 4</td>
        <td>dfdf</td>

        <td>Y</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLoginForm">
            Edit
          </button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">5</th>
        <td>TV 5</td>
        <td>dfdf</td>

        <td>Y</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLoginForm">
            Edit
          </button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">6</th>
        <td>TV 6</td>
        <td>dfdf</td>

        <td>Y</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLoginForm">
            Edit
          </button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">7</th>
        <td>TV 7</td>
        <td>dfdf</td>

        <td>Y</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLoginForm">
            Edit
          </button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="ModalLoginForm" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-body">
          <form role="form" method="POST" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Channel No</label>
              <div>
                <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="channelid" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Channel Name</label>
              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="channel">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Description</label>
              <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="description">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Channel Recordable
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>


              </div>
            </div>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this..!! this is exactly what i needed .:) :)
Can you please help me where i can learn to use bootstrap related jquery for further understanding..!!

Comment: @nskniranga1127 I have un-deleted my answer - please consider accepting the answer if it has helped you and i provided full working solution to you - Good accepted answer help **other users** on this site as well. Let me know if i can help your further :)

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: @nskniranga1127 I appreciate that. Thank you. Regarding the jQuery /Javascript learning related bootstrap you can [visit here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/) - there are alot of usefull official resources and examples :)

Comment: If possible I have two questions i need to clarify.
1.)Is it possible to do add a javascript function to bootstrap (like onclick function for this without jquery)
2.) since there jquery functions available specific to bootstrap. where i can get an idea about this ?
I'm liittle bit new to this :)

Comment: @nskniranga1127 I have mentioned the official web learning resource in my comment for you already. And Regarding JavaScript function without jQuery yes it possible. Actually jQuery is JavaScript  anyway. Bootstrap Natively itself uses jQuery to handle all the function for example modal opening / closing. So i would recemend using jQuery library for boostrap related projects. if its something else then you can native JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".table .btn-info").on("click", function(){ //now it aply for every .btn-info in every .table... so its better to make a new class or id for your table
    var thContentFromThisRow = $(this).closest("tr").find("th").html(); // copy data from the TH in the same ROW as your clicked button

    $('[name="channelid"]').val(thContentFromThisRow); //here you select your desired input to fill by name and then use .val (short for value) and you insert your data...
});
```

This is a short way of collecting one inner html from your th inside row of your button. Just to show how it worsk. Anyway you should go to w3c or another basics page and learn the basics of js/jquery. This code I've written is in jquery since you have bootstrap.